# a system of simultaneous linear differential equations with constant coefficients

Tags: differential

> Solve the system of differential equations:
>   $$
> \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}x=2y, \quad
> \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}y=2x, \quad
> \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}z=2x
> $$

I tried solving the first two equations by eliminating $y$ and solving for $x$, which gives
$$x(t)=c_1e^{2t}+c_2e^{-2t},$$
but the answer is somewhat different.
Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure that $\dot y=2x$ and not $2z$?

Comment: yes sir i'm sure it's Dy=2x

Comment: If the problem has been reported correctly, then the solution is what you've written.